# ordered list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

i need to create a python function that reads and lists groceries from a file called "food.txt" such that when ever a new line in the textfile is found, a new list grouping within the general list is created.

food.txt:

```
milk
cheese
bread

steak
chicken
potatoes
```

^ each word should be on its own line with a single new line between the groups

output: [['milk','cheese','bread'],['steak','chicken','potatoes']]

so far i have:

```
   def build_grocery_list(file_name):
        outer_list=[]
        inner_list=[]

        food_list=open(file_name,"r")
        for line in food_list:
            line.strip('\n') # no white spaces in the list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4089505)):

```
list_of_lists=[]
category=0
list_of_lists.append([])

f = open(file_name,'r')

for line in f.readlines():
    item = line.strip('\n') # no white spaces in the list
    if len(item) > 0:
         #add to current category
         list_of_lists[category].append(item)
    else:
         #add new category
         list_of_lists.append([])
         category = category + 1
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start! You can check if the line you are reading is not empty (`len(line.strip('\n')) > 0`) If it is not, append the line content to `inner_list`, if it is empty, append the full `inner_list` to `outer_list` and start with a new `inner_list`.